# Format HTML in Freemarker templates in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: html, intellij-idea, formatting, freemarker

The automatic formatting style of IntelliJ IDEA 2018.1.3 seems to not apply to Freemarker templates (.ftl) with HTML tags in them. When applying code formatting with `CMD+CTRL+L` this is what happens:

[image]

Instead of what seems to be more correct:

[image]

Is there any formatting option to make Freemarker format in the same way as HTML does, following the correct page indentation?

Comment: Currently, IDEA don't have any special handling for HTML/FreeMarker nesting, because it's not clear how it should work, especially in cases when structures don't match. HTML formatter doesn't (and can't) do anything about FreeMarker tags because they're not HTML. Could you please explain what "correct page indentation" you expect? And preferably why you believe it's correct.

Comment: I think correct indentation would be for Frermarker tags to follow their sorry ding HTML indentation, essentially behave like any HTML block tag. It'd be easier to read long files if that was how they were formatted as you could follow opening and closing of tags...

Answer (score 0):

Changing the template output to XHTML seems to ensure that at most tags are indented the way it should.